# Always add a default where clause to searchkick queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a usecase where in each session I need to dd a where clause to all searchkick queries. This is basically a case where I have data from multiple clients in multiple DBs and the searchkick index contains a field called client_id.

I dont want to keep doing it for all the queries. Is there some way by which I can say add a where: {client_id: "XXXX"} to all searchkick queries in this session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine singleton method to add the 'where :' parameter automatically, after `searchkick` in class definition add:

```
class<<Product
  alias oldsearch search
    def search(s, l, o)
      oldsearch s, where: {client_id: "XXXX"}, limit: l, offset: o
    end
end
```

---

```
$ irb
2.2.0 :001 > class A

# searchkick adds his methods to your model like this:

2.2.0 :002?>   class<<self
2.2.0 :003?>     def a
2.2.0 :004?>       puts 'a'
2.2.0 :005?>       end
2.2.0 :006?>     end

# and you are adding following:

2.2.0 :007?>   class<<self
2.2.0 :008?>     alias b a
2.2.0 :009?>     def a
2.2.0 :010?>       puts 'a-new'
2.2.0 :011?>       b
2.2.0 :012?>       end
2.2.0 :013?>     end
2.2.0 :014?>   end
 => :a 
2.2.0 :015 > A.a #=> a-new
                 #   a
```

---

And, of course, you can just create a wrapper method which calls `Product.search` with parameters you need.